# Unable to render async Django REST API response in React table

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, react-table

```
import React , { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'
import ReactTable from "react-table-6";  
import "react-table-6/react-table.css" 


 class Users extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = ({
          users: [],
          loading: true,
        })
      }

      async getUsersData(){
        const res = await axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/...`)

        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data.data)
              this.setState({
                  users: [res.data]
              })
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
          })
      }
      componentDidMount(){
        this.getUsersData()
      }

    render() {


        const columns = [{  
            Header: 'ID',  
            accessor: 'id',
           }
           ,{  
            Header: 'Password',  
            accessor: 'password' ,
            }
           
           ,{  
           Header: 'Email',  
           accessor: 'email' ,
           }
           ,{  
           Header: 'First Name',  
           accessor: 'first_name',
           },
           {  
            Header: 'Last Name',  
            accessor: 'last_name',
            },
           
        ]

        return (
           
            <ReactTable  
            data={this.state.users}  
            columns={columns}  
          
         />

     
           );
           
    }

}

export default Users;
```

This generates a response in the console, but does not populate the table.

What needs to be fixed to render the response in the React table

Comment: check the users array. I think the data inside this.state.users maybe in wrong format.

Comment: This is how the response looks like(unfortunately i can not attach an image):0:
data: Array(13)
0:
email: "abc@gmail.com"
first_name: "abc"
id: 1
is_active: true
is_staff: true
is_superuser: true

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.